# Is there an up-to-date (crx3) way to build a chromium extension (Edge+Chrome) using a CI jenkins pipeline (maven+nexus preferably)?

Tags: maven, jenkins, google-chrome-extension, chromium, microsoft-edge-extension

I am building a self-hosted chromium extension for Edge and Chrome. So far I got a nice working CI pipeline using maven with this plugin (https://github.com/bmatthews68/crx-maven-plugin) and I managed to automate the versioning, packaging and signing of the .crx file, and upload to Nexus repository without much hassle (our intent was to point the upload URL to Nexus releases using group policies to get the extension deployed to users).

But we have found that the plugin is a bit outdated and uses crx2 format for the extension packaging. Support for crx2 was dropped a while ago (chromium v75 or so), and current browser versions require crx3 or won't install the extension.

Seems like the only reliable way to package a crx3 extension right now is using the chrome executable itself, but it does not look like the best idea for a CI pipeline :-/

Any suggestion is welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a way, though indirect. There is a CRX3 NPM project that has been kept up to date for the CRX3 format at https://www.npmjs.com/package/crx3

Using exec-maven-plugin to invoke NPM as detailed below, I've been able to package the crx file correctly (and this works in local windows workstations and ALM linux nodes):

```
            <!-- Build crx file using NPM -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <phase>compile</phase>                  
                <goals>
                  <goal>exec</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
              <executable>npm</executable>                
              <workingDirectory>${project.build.directory}</workingDirectory>
              <commandlineArgs>install</commandlineArgs>
            </configuration>                
        </plugin>
```

I used a package.json file for NPM with placeholders for version so I could keep on managing the version in the pom:

```
{
  "name": "${project.artifactId}",
  "version": "${project.version}",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "crx3": "^1.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "install": "crx3 ${project.artifactId}-${project.version} --keyPath crx.pem --appVersion ${crx.version} --crxPath ${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.crx"
  }
}
```

For the filtering to work correctly I used maven-resources plugin in the pom as well:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>copy-extension-resources</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>resources</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</outputDirectory>
                    <resources>
                        <!-- Resource filtering to include version number in manifest.json and copy sources to a subfolder in /target -->
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/main/chrome</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/manifest.json</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/main/chrome</directory>
                            <filtering>false</filtering>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>**/manifest.json</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>copy-external-resources</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>resources</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                    <resources>
                        <!-- Resource filtering to include version number in update.xml and package.json and copy resources to /target folder -->
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                            <includes>
                                <include>update.xml</include>
                                <include>package.json</include>
                                <include>package-lock.json</include>    
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                        <resource>
                            <filtering>false</filtering>
                            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>                   
                            <includes>
                                <include>crx.pem</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
            </execution>

        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, `CRX2` was deprecated in Chrome 75 two years ago, there are [some issues](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1pAVB4y5EBhqufLshWMcvbQ5velk0yMGl5ynqiorTCG4/edit#heading=h.wwgnimruvhlu) with CRX₂ and its support was completely removed in Chrome 78. Because all extensions must move to the CRX3 format!

I'm not sure how you built it with maven, maybe it was a script or something. In this case, you may need to modify your script appropriately, or find some reference documents that support `CRX3` format related to the tools you are using to build the extension.

Otherwise you have to package it in crx3 format. Refer to this [document](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/linux_hosting/#packaging).

Comment: Thanks for the info. The link to the maven plugin is included in the description :-)
Sadly, it's unmaintained now... :-(

Comment: If this is the case, you have no other choice, you have to pack it into CRX3 format as mentioned above.

Comment: I tried the path of crx packaging using the chrome executable via exec-maven-plugin, but I couldn't manage to get it working in jenkins nodes (it required headless run of the chrome executable in docker nodes... hardest than rocket science!)